# Find which array an item is in given multiple arrays and item only exists in one in PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an ecommerce website and I have it set up that countries are split into different zones for shipping costs.

I have 8 zones, these are all arrays of country codes, there can be no duplicates in the arrays or items can't exist in multiple arrays.

I then want to calculate the shipping costs for a given country. So I basically want to find out which zone the country is in.

What I do at the moment is I query my shipping zones by the items supplier to get all of the arrays and then do an `if(in_array())` on each of these like so:

```
$params = [$supplier_id];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shipping_zones WHERE supplier_id=?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $z1 = unserialize($row['zone1']);
    $z2 = unserialize($row['zone2']);
    $z3 = unserialize($row['zone3']);
    $z4 = unserialize($row['zone4']);
    $z5 = unserialize($row['zone5']);
    $z6 = unserialize($row['zone6']);
    $z7 = unserialize($row['zone7']);
    $z8 = unserialize($row['zone8']);
}

if(in_array($country_code,$z1)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z1';
}else if(in_array($country_code,$z2)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z2';
}else if(in_array($country_code,$z3)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z3';
}else if(in_array($country_code,$z4)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z4';
}else if(in_array($country_code,$z5)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z5';
}else if(in_array($country_code,$z6)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z6';
}else if(in_array($country_code,$z7)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z7';
}else if(in_array($country_code,$z8)){
    $shipping_zone = 'z8';
}
```

There has to be a better way of doing this, I thought it might be easier to do it in the initial SQL query but the actual arrays are serialized in the DB.

Comment: First of all you could normalize the `shipping_zones` and make a table `shipping_zone_supplier`

Comment: Modify the `where` clause on your query to look through each of the columns for the country code. Though a crude approach it should work. Take the advise of ka_lin though and normalize the information. Would make your query simpler and faster.

Comment: When you say "There has to be a better way of doing this...but the actual arrays are serialized in the DB", do you mean that you need a solution that doesn't involve changing your database schema?  And if so, can the solution involve changing the shape of the serialized data?  Or are you trying to find a clean way to inspect into data you don't control?

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If possible try and restructure this into a one-to-many relational structure as that will make your code a lot more concise and understandable and your queries dramatically simpler. Even if you can't restructure **learn about using loops** to simplify code like this. The repetition here is deafening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it looks like the schema for shipping_zones looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE shipping_zones (
  supplier_id INT,
  zone1 TEXT, -- Each of these contains a big serialized PHP array
  zone2 TEXT,
  zone3 TEXT,
  zone4 TEXT,
  zone5 TEXT,
  zone6 TEXT,
  zone7 TEXT,
  zone8 TEXT
);
```

It sounds like there are 2 things you'd like to accomplish here:

1. Maintain data integrity (*"there can be no duplicates in the arrays or items can't exist in multiple arrays"*)
2. Make your code simpler/more maintainable (*"There has to be a better way of doing this..."*)

Assuming you have full control over the application and the database, I would recommend changing your database schema so that your RDBMS can do more work for you.  I suggest a schema that looks more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE shipping_zones (
  supplier_id  INT,
  zone         ENUM('z1','z2','z3','z4','z5','z6','z7','z8') NOT NULL,
  country_code CHAR(2) -- Not really sure what your codes actually look like...
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique ON shipping_zones(supplier_id, country_code);
```

This way you can't accidentally put a country in multiple zones for a given supplier, and your task of getting the correct code for the given supplier becomes as simple as the following query:

```
SELECT 
  zone 
FROM 
  shipping_zones 
WHERE 
  supplier_id = :supplier_id 
  AND country_code = :country_code;
```

Comment: Why `VARCHAR(5000)` instead of `TEXT`?

Comment: No particular reason.  I'll change it if you think it makes the answer read better.

Comment: The 5000 part is oddly specific and makes assumptions about how big the data is. `TEXT` is 65535 by default, but `MEDIUMTEXT` and `LONGTEXT` can be used if required.

Comment: Also try and indicate values as placeholders like `?` or `:supplier_id`. Using `$supplier_id` encourages reckless SQL injections.

Comment: @tadman, to be fair, that whole block of code is an assumption.  The OP did not provide a datamodel, so I guessed at it.

Comment: @tadman, fair point on the placeholders.  I have updated my answer accordingly.